# Model is null when the endpoint is hit via postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

It seems like the data that I am passing through postman isnt matching the model that is in the controller method.
I am implementing web api endpoint in .Net application to handle saving of muliple File uploads at the same time. The user could select multiple files and for each file he could select the document type and date. There are two tables (parent and child) that the records are inserted into
The parent table in my example is DOCUMENT table and child records are stored in the MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT table. Is there anything wrong with my JSON structure

Viewmodel

```
 public class DocumentUploadCreateViewModel
    {
        public int ManagerStrategyId { get; set; }
        public List<DocumentUploadCreateDetailsViewModel> DocumentUploadCreateDetailsViewModel = new List<DocumentUploadCreateDetailsViewModel>();
    }


 public class DocumentUploadCreateDetailsViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DocumentDate { get; set; }
        public byte[] DocumentContent { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
        [SkipTokenAuthorization]
        [Route("api/documentupload/create")]
        public IHttpActionResult Create(DocumentUploadCreateViewModel model)
        {
            var mgrStrategyDocument = new MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT();
        var mgrDocumentService = GetService<DOCUMENT>();
        var mgrStrategyDocumentService = GetService<MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT>();

        if (model != null)
        {
            foreach (var obj in model.DocumentUploadCreateDetailsViewModel)
            {
                var mgrDocument = new DOCUMENT
                {
                    DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID = obj.DocumentTypeId,
                    DOCUMENT_DATE = obj.DocumentDate,
                    NAME = obj.Name
                };
                mgrDocument = mgrDocumentService.Create(mgrDocument);


                var mangerStrategyDocumentService = GetService<MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT>();
                var mgrStrategyDocument1 = new MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT()
                {
                    DOCUMENT_ID = mgrDocument.ID,
                    MANAGERSTRATEGY_ID = model.ManagerStrategyId

                };
                mgrStrategyDocument = mgrStrategyDocumentService.Create(mgrStrategyDocument1);
            }

        }
        return Ok(mgrStrategyDocument);

    }
    }
```

Postman

```
http://localhost:56888/api/documentupload/create


JSON

    {
    "ManagerStrategyId" : 5508,

    [
        "Name" : "x2",
        "DocumentTypeId" : 2,
        "DocumentDate" : "15/04/2010",
        "DocumentContent" : [71,107,98]
    ],

        [
        "Name" : "x3",
        "DocumentTypeId" : 3,
        "DocumentDate" : "15/04/2010",
        "DocumentContent" : [71,107,98]
    ],

        [
        "Name" : "x4",
        "DocumentTypeId" : 4,
        "DocumentDate" : "15/04/2010",
        "DocumentContent" : [71,107,98]
    ]
}
```

Comment: There's probably have something logged in the ModelState property of the Controller?

Comment: Sorry didnt get you ?

Comment: Sorry for the broken sentence! If that's a WebAPI / MVC controller, you'll have a ModelState property there, That will usually log some error when the model is null - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.modelstate?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: Its WEBAPI. I tried to debug the ModelState and it shows     Count: 1
    IsReadOnly: false
    IsValid: false
    Keys: Count = 1
    Values: Count = 1
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable

Comment: Yeah, the 1 item in that list will be your error message - Expand the enumerable in the debug view and you'll see it

Comment: This is the error message Invalid property identifier character: [. Path 'ManagerStrategyId', line 4, position 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195216/discussion-between-tom-and-sam).

Comment: The JSON seems to be invalid when putting it in the JSON formatter tool . Not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is missing the key for the list and also the list syntax seems incorrect. Try the following:

```
{
"ManagerStrategyId":5508,
"DocumentUploadCreateDetailsViewModel":[
  {
     "Name":"x2",
     "DocumentTypeId":2,
     "DocumentDate":"2010-04-15",
     "DocumentContent":[
        71,
        107,
        98
     ]
  },
  {
     "Name":"x3",
     "DocumentTypeId":3,
     "DocumentDate":"2010-04-15",
     "DocumentContent":[
        71,
        107,
        98
     ]
  },
  {
     "Name":"x4",
     "DocumentTypeId":4,
     "DocumentDate":"2010-04-15",
     "DocumentContent":[
        71,
        107,
        98
     ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Looks good except the DocumentDate is coming null. Its DateTime field in the model

Comment: @Tom I assume the DateTime should be the  ISO 8601 standard: "2012-03-19T07:22Z" format. I have updated the answer with the ISO format.